# Como configurar gulp.task default sass e watch

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, gulp

olá
estou com alguns problemas na configuração do gulpfile.js para automatizar a conversão de sass para css no projeto de teste, abaixo explico o ambiente e os erros apresentados

Estrutura das pastas

> ```
> //layout
> | |/node_modules
> | |/src
> | | /css
> | |   |bootstrap-grid.css
> | |   |bootstrap-reboot.css
> | |   |bootstrap.css
> | |   |style.css
> | | /js
> | |   |bootstrap.js
> | |   |jquery.js
> | |   |popper.js
> | | /scss
> | |   |style.scss
> | |index.html
> |gulpfile.js
> |package-lock.json
> |package.json
> ```

no arquivo layout/src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!--meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Bootstrap.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery, Popper.js, Bootstrap.js -->

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

o arquivo layout/gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var watch = require('gulp-watch');

//task para o sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass()) //converter o sass em css
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"));
});

//task para watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], ['sass']);
});

//task para default gulp
//gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```

comentei a task default pois ao executar o comando $gulp no terminal cmd ou bash retorna um erro

```
$ gulp
assert.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\bs_wp\layout\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\bs_wp\layout\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\bs_wp\layout\gulpfile.js:18:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
```

então comentei a tarefa default e rodei o código com o comando $gulp watch que inicia porém apresenta problema logo em seguida

```
$ gulp watch
[01:54:32] Using gulpfile C:\bs_wp\layout\gulpfile.js
[01:54:32] Starting 'watch'...
[01:54:32] 'watch' errored after 7.05 ms
[01:54:32] Error: watching node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*.scss,src/scss/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
    at Gulp.watch (C:\bs_wp\layout\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11)
    at C:\bs_wp\layout\gulpfile.js:14:10
    at taskWrapper (C:\bs_wp\layout\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\bs_wp\layout\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

não tenho muito conhecimento na área li sobre o gulp.parallel e gulp.series mas meu inglês é ruim, n absorvi direito a informação a configuração do gulp ficou meio confusa pra mim

Answer (score 1):

Seu código do gulpfile.js tem alguns detalhes, mas o principal é que vc não está colocando a função dentro do `gulp.series` e nem usando o `gulp.parallel( ['sass'] )` na task

Teste colocando exatamente esse script abaixo substituindo o que está dentro do seu `gulpfile.js` que a sua task deve rodar.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', gulp.series( function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass()) // converter o Sass em CSS
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
}));

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series( function() {
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.parallel( ['sass'] ));
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series( ['sass', 'watch'] ));
```